# Cannot resolve binding in datatrigger wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, foreground

Using this code:

```
  <DataGrid
    Grid.Row="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding DdaOptions.FilteredRecords.FilteredRecords}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    GridLinesVisibility="None"
    Background="{StaticResource White1}"
    BorderThickness="1"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource White1}"
    Style="{StaticResource Roboto10DataGrid}"
    AreRowDetailsFrozen="True"
    CanUserAddRows="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="GuideNumber" Binding="{Binding GuideNumber}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PartNumber" Binding="{Binding PartNumber}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Options" Binding="{Binding Options}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PartStock" Binding="{Binding PartStock}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="InterventionType" Binding="{Binding InterventionType}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsInDda}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DarkAccent1}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlighted}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Foreground">
            <Setter.Value>
             <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding DdaOptions.MyColor}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

the binding `Color="{Binding DdaOptions.MyColor}"` does not work. If I replace the line

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding DdaOptions.MyColor}"/>
```

with this line

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
```

it works. Using debug the DdaOptions.MyColor property is properly set.
How can I change the code in order to solve this problem?
I've tried to use a converter instead of

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding DdaOptions.MyColor}"/>
```

but the problem still remains.
The type of the property MyColor is Color.
Dda is the ViewModel and it implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Using this code

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlighted}" Value="True">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding DdaOptions.MyColor}"/>
 </DataTrigger>
```

instead of

```
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlighted}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
      <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding DdaOptions.MyColor}"/>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </DataTrigger>
```

The color change always as black. MyColor is a Brush and I set it in this way:

```
MyColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(myColor.R, myColor.G, yColor.B));
```

Comment: instead of this <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding DdaOptions.MyColor}"/>,

try like this,
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=(DdaOptions.MyColor)}"/> if that is AttachedProperty

Comment: ... and what is `DdaOptions` ?

Comment: DdaOptions is a ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Is `.Mycolor` static ? if yes you could move it to the `XAML` and use `StaticResource`.

Comment: It isn't static

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: You would also have to explain what `daOptions` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

if `DdaOptions.MyColor` is of type `SolidColorBrush` then use this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlighted}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.DdaOptions.MyColor}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

or if of type `Color` then this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlighted}" Value="True">
  <Setter Property="Foreground">
    <Setter.Value>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.DdaOptions.MyColor}"/>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

And of course your have to change `AncestorType=Window` to the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

If the DdaOptions.MyColor source property returns a *Brush* you should set the Foreground property to this brush directly:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlighted}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding DdaOptions.MyColor}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Yes I did it but the color changes always in black. In debug I can see that MyColor (MyColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(myColor.R, myColor.G, myColor.B));) is properly set but I see always black on the UI

Comment: Use a different brush then: DdaOptions.MyColor = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow; You can't really expect anyone to know that exact color you expect to be displayed based on the information you have provided...

Comment: It still does not work. I have a group of buttons and a grid. Each button has a customized background color. When I click on a button the foreground of the rows in the grid should change accordingly to the color of the clicked button.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code that shows how you set the Highlighted property then. Make sure that the class where this property is defined implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface correctly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx